# Can I Find a .EXE File to Install FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

NEW, totally NEW to FFMPEG.  I'm confused about installation.  For most programs of this type I've seen .EXE files.

I couldn't find that for FFMPEG.  Is there one for a 64-bit win machine?

So far, I found a .ZIP file.  BUT...within the file, I can't see what there is to effectuate the installation.  Here's where I am at:

[image: What I'm seeing is this]

What's next?

Comment: There's no installation. The exe files are in the bin folder.

Comment: @Carl The executables are `ffmpeg`, `ffplay` and `ffprobe`. As already indicated, they are simply run as-is from the command line. Note there is no GUI interface by default. All your input/encoding/playback parameters are text options specified after the given executable name.

Comment: Hi @Gyan & @Anaksunaman!  So, sounds like, if I want to run 11.206 selectivecolor then there'll be no slider generated.  Only results. That is, I'll see the outcome but every time I want to try to change something I would simply need to alter the variables, and then re-run the command line. Am I right?  And, if so, what's the easiest way for me to have a very light weight control over white balance?

Answer (score 4):

FFMpeg has a [command line interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) (remember [MS-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS)?). You type a command and press enter and then it runs.

You are probably used to a [graphical user interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface).

There are many graphical user interfaces built around FFMpeg. Try https://www.shutterencoder.com/en/ for example. If you google "ffmpeg gui" you can find many more.